# Difference between dates always returns a default number(5) in the database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Hello I'm just having a little trouble with a function, to explain it first it's supposed to get the difference between two dates and take that number then subtract it from a field on the database and it works well or so I thought until I noticed that whatever date I put it always returns only the number 5
Leave Model

```
protected $dates = ['from', 'to'];

public function numberOfDays()
{

    $datesx =Leave::where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)
                ->first();

    $from =$datesx->from;
    $to =$datesx->to;

    $datetime1 = new DateTime($from);
    $datetime2 = new DateTime($to);

    $interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
    $days = $interval->format('%a');//now do whatever you like with $days
    return $days;
}
```

User Model

```
public function leaveBalance()
{
    $leave =new Leave;
    $daysUsed= $leave->numberOfDays();
    // $daysUsed = $this->leaves->map->numberOfDays()->sum();
    // return $this->leave_days_granted - $daysUsed;
    $days_granted = User::where('id', auth()->user()->id)
    ->first();

    $leave_days_granted = $days_granted->leave_days_granted;
    return $leave_days_granted - $daysUsed;
}

public function hasAvailableLeave()
{
    return $this->leaveBalance() > 0;
}

public function leaves()
{
    return $this->hasMany(\App\Leave::class);
}
```

Leave Controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request,[
        'from'=>'required',
        'to'=>'required',
        'description'=>'required',
        'type'=>'required'
        ]);
    $data=$request->all();
    $data['user_id']=auth()->user()->id;
    $data['message']='';
    $data['status']=0;
    $leave =Leave::create($data);

    /** update users table with leaveBalance() return value*/
    //get logged in user id
    $user_id=auth()->user()->id;

    //get the returned value from User model method
    $leave_balance = new User;

    // $leave_balance->leaveBalance();
    // dd($leave_balance->leaveBalance());
    // die();
        

    DB::table('users')
        ->where('id', $user_id)
        ->update(['leave_days_granted' => $leave_balance->leaveBalance()]);
```

By only returns the number 5 I mean is that every time a leave is requested/stored it subtracts -5 from the field leave_days_granted but it's supposed to subtract the difference between the two dates that is given in the leave table, fields "from" and "to" which stores the date from and to a specific date

Comment: So what format are the dates on the database. I would hope they are DATETIME or DATE types but I have to ask as if they are defines as something else that is the most likely reason for an issue

Comment: They are DATE types the field "from" and "to" are DATE and the field leave_days_granted which is on the user table is an int which I guess i just assumed should be because it's supposed to do the math and return the value subtracted was I wrong to assume that?

Comment: Every time you call store it should create new Leave row in db and substract that one? You always fetch the first one `Leave::where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)->first();` not the current (last one) and i guess the first one was with 5 days diff.

Comment: Thank you that was the reason indeed I added a ->latest() before the ->first() and now it takes the value from the latest one created

Comment: Hello , I think this package helps you https://github.com/spatie/period